# can I make C programs interact with linux pipes

Tags: c, linux

I want to combine my C programs with commands in the linux shell. One example would be as following.

```
# I want to print the third column of the csv.
$ cat example.csv
1,2,3
a,b,,c
one,two,four,,
# I want to achieve this with linux pipes
$ cat example.csv | ./project 3
3

four
$
```

My main goal is to make my programs take input from unix pipes. The closest thing I've managed is the pipe() function but that is only for paralell processes within the C program which is not what I want.

Is there any support for this in C? Or would I need to use something else?

Comment: Yes, you could program this yourself. Or use awk. [BTW: the program `./project` does not *see* a pipe. It just reads stdin (which happens to come from a pipe)]

Comment: The shell command `cat example.csv | ./project 3` will call your program in a way so that its `stdin` is the output from `cat`. Your program probably doesn't need to care where its input came from or do anything special. Just use the normal input functions.

Comment: (Also `./project 3 < example.csv` will do almost exactly the same thing as `cat example.csv | ./project 3`)

Comment: You can only connect parent-child processes or processes which have a common ancestor with pipes. To commuincate between any two arbitrary processes, use an IPC mechanism like message queues.